# How to make `transition: rotate` use the shortest rotation?

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions

I'd like to assign rotation in steps to an element, e.g. 90deg. At the same time, it has to have an initial offset rotation, e.g. 1deg, that should apply to all steps. Let's say I need 1, 91, 181 and 271 degree. So far so easy. But now I also want smooth CSS transitions.

Till 271deg this works, but if I go back to 1, the transition goes all the way back counter-clock wise (271->181->91->1), but I would like it to take the 'visually short' route e.g. 271->272->273...->1 (=361).

Here is an example. Replace the div's r-271 with r-1 in a browser's HTML editor.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.r {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.r-1 {
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}

.r-91 {
  transform: rotate(91deg);
}

.r-181 {
  transform: rotate(181deg);
}

.r-271 {
  transform: rotate(271deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="r r-271">X</div>
```

Using a `.r-361` is not an option for me, as my application's data model only stores the 4 steps in this case and I don't know the previous state. So I need this to work with 4 classes/states only, and also with negative original rotations, e.g. -1/89/179/269). No JavaScript animations, please.

(90deg is just an example, It should work with various kinds of steps.)

Comment: Are you allowed/able to alter the HTML?

Comment: I have a stateless API, but a 'rich' client. After pulling new API data I can read the old DOM and change it. Animations only have to survive in the browser session, it is not necessary to see them after a page refresh. Basically a user is rotating game pieces/token in steps here and should see it in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @a-haworth's answer, I settled with a solution that mixes 360° pre-rotation with a pure transition approach. I had to add two extra classes:

```css
.r-271-cw {
  transform: rotate(-91deg);
  transition: none;
}
.r-1-ccw {
  transform: rotate(361deg);
  transition: none;
}
```

Before I set the new rotation class into the existing element, I query the old class from the node:

- If the class was `.r-271` and is about to become `.r-1`, I assign the element the classes `.r-1.r-271-cw`.
- If the class was `.r-1` and is about to become `.r-271`, I assign the element the classes `.r-271.r-1-ccw`.
- In any other case I just apply the new rotation class without helper class.
- After a few ms I remove any `.r-271-cw` or `.r-1-ccw` class in my DOM.

The additional cw/ccw classes reset the previous rotation of their element to a degree that is 360°/-360° ahead, so the rotation can pick up at that position for a proper (counter)clockwise turn. At the same time, the additional classes disable transition so the the element jumps to the new rotation without any visual impact. When I remove the cw/ccw classes, this re-enables the transitions and the element now uses the 'shortest rotation'.

This approach also works well with any direction change or even skipping steps, as no animations have to be aborted.

(I also switched to CSS variables and cumulative rotations for the extra 1°, but that is not needed for this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use CSS animations and to have a 'basic' 0, 90, 180, 270 set of rotations, but to make use of the fact that CSS transforms are cumulative, so you can both rotate by one of those values and then by whatever the step value is.

In the question this is set at 1deg but in this snippet it is set at -20deg to show it works when the step value is negative. A CSS variable is used to set the step value so it is easy for you to change.

The final rotation is made to go 'the shortest route' by always having it going from -90deg to 0deg rather than 270deg to 0deg.

For this demo the rotate button just moves to the next rotation on each click. The names of the classes have been simplified to r1-r4 to make it easier to calculate which one to use next.

```js
//This script is just to make the button work for the demo.
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
let n = 1;
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.classList.remove('r' + n);;
  n = (n == 4) ? 1 : n + 1;
  div.classList.add('r' + n);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.r {
  --step: -20deg;
}

.r1 {
  animation: r1 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes r1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
}

.r2 {
  animation: r2 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes r2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
}

.r3 {
  animation: r3 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes r3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
}

.r4 {
  animation: r4 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes r4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg) rotate(var(--step));
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Rotate</button>
<div class="r r1">X</div>
```

Comment: This is a good step in the right direction, but how to avoid the 'jump' when going directly from e.g. r4 directly to r2? I guess I could add all combinations, e.g. .r1-r2, .r1-r3 and so forth, since I have the previous state at least in the DOM in the class name, but I need then to smoothly cancel the animation half-way if the rotation change happens faster than the animation.